# Cannot install Apache server due to admin permissions

Tags: windows-10, permissions, apache-http-server, user-accounts

I downloaded and installed C++ Redistributable Visual Studio 2017 for win64 from [apachelounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/). No errors here.

From the same page I also downloaded the Apache win64 zip. I try to get the downloaded zip in the `C:` in order to unzip it and then config it/set it as a service.

The problem : When I try to drag the downloaded zip to the `C:` , I get

> You'll need to provide administrator permission to move this folder.
>   [Continue] [Skip] [Cancel]

And says that the folder size is 886 GB, while right-clicking the zip and going to properties says the size is just 15MB.

Facts : 
By right-clicking the zip and going to "Security", the group of users are : System, slevin(SLEVINLAPTOP\slevin) and Administrators(SLEVINLAPTOP\Administrators). They all have all the permissions, except "Special permissions".

I am the only one that uses the laptop, there is only my user account and I am the admin. In my account's info, says "Local Account / Administrator". I have Win 10 Home, 64bit.

How can I fix this, so I can install Apache properly? Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You installed the C++ Redistributable that came with Vs2017 but that doesn't mean you installed the C++ Redistributable required by Apache.  So what version does Apache require and did you install it?

Comment: The root directory of your system drive is a protected directory which means you must be an Administrator to extra a file into a folder contained within the root directory.  So are you using an Administrator account?

Comment: Solution:  Install Apache to a non-protected directory

Answer (score 1):

First, download the .zip file to your local Download directory first and unpack it there.

Then move the extracted files to your C: drive under a new folder you have created (e.g. C:\Web\apache).

If Windows continues to prompt you provide administrator permissions to move items, simply click "Continue".

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved it, may be useful to others.

In the C folder, I right-click to get to the properties and then, in the "Security" tab I added the Users(SLEVINLAPTOP\Users) in the Group of users, with the following permissions : Read&Execute, List of folder contents, Read

I downloaded the zip and left it in the Download directory. I used winRAR to unzipit from Downloads to C.

Now Apache works fine, even though I am not sure of what the problem was in the first place, or if there is still a problem I have to solve.

If there is any other solution or remarks, please let me know

Thanks

Comment: As I said, the root directory of the system partition is protected, the Downloads user profile directory isn't